# "app not installed" error on expo android app

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I can't just "update" the existing app developed by expo. I can install the app successfully. The message says that the app not installed. But this happens when I try to update the existing old version app. and it appears on android on various devices.  this is my app.json code.  [app.json](https://www.github.com/sungho0205/react-native-Geupsik/tree/master/app.json)

Comment: Are you referring to an update from the Play Store post publish not going out to users who have the app already installed?

Comment: No. I builded my app by expo build:android and I installed .apk to my phone.

Comment: Why not download the Expo Client app on your phone? You can then build the project, when the terminal opens with the QR barcode - scan it into the Expo Client app.  Doing so, enabled you to see live changes and hot reloading.

Comment: I usually test in the ios simulator, and I wanted to build it and see if it's alright.